# Robot.Delay(ms) freezes my application - Java

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I have been trying to delay a simple piece of code in Java for a while, unfortunately if use a thread then the following code will not work as it is apart of the thread and i get lots of exceptions.

I am trying to delay another way like this:

```
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);

                    //My code here..
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is, is that it freezes my hole application just like Thread.sleep(ms) would do if you slept the main thread of the application.

I was wondering if there is any way around it freezing my hole application.

Comment: Why are you using the Robot class?  The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations.

Comment: Can you suggest any other possible way of delaying without it freezing my application please?

Comment: You cannot put a sleep in the AWT thread without it freezing the UI. You will need to explain further why you cannot put your code in a new thread.